# NMake Optional Dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile, build, nmake

We’re currently upgrading our archaic build system from a bunch of batch scripts to a makefile system using NMake.  It’s challenging as we use a custom intermediate language that ends up getting translated to C++ where some of our translators can generate 10’s of files what have a common parts in the file names.  The other challenging thing is we use a bunch of CSV files to configure our interfaces and these files get passed through to our configuration tools which generate more source code files.  Right now I am focusing on creating the simple rules for our configuration files but can’t seem to figure out a way associate a dependency with a rule if the dependency exists.  I tried to use $(wildcard xxx.csv) but found out that this command doesn’t exist for NMake like it does for GNU Make.

So how can I create my rule so that it executes and runs my commands if I have two dependency csv files that will always exists and a third csv file that will exist only when my project calls for it?

Answer (score 0):

> [..] will exist only when my project calls for it?

This is a bit unclear. Assuming that there is a command that - depending on some external circumstances - might generate that third csv file, you could use a "stamp file" (I think they call it "pseudo target" in NMAKE):

```
stamp:
    command_that_might_generate_csv3
    touch stamp # updates timestamp of "stamp" (or creates it)

target: csv1 csv2 stamp
    command_using_all_of csv1 csv2 csv3
```

Comment: Sorry, that is vague. Let me clarify that.  I'm trying to make this makefile a tad generic so that we can use it for multiple project that are using this tool set.  If anything is project specific it will get moved into a separate file.  So our system has a set number of defined CSV files used to configure the system depending on the cards we have plugged into our rack.  A handful of CSV files have to exist the other only have to exist if the associated hardware will be used.  Hopefully that makes sense